# How display data in a gallery view mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview, view, gallery

Is there a way to display gridview as "gallery view" instead of  plain "list view". For example like ebay(you can toggle the view 1.list view, 2.gallery view, 3. side by side view). Any asp.net controls or jQuery controls will do the job for me. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to use the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) server control to make a template that looks like the "Gallery View" you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you TheGeekYouNeed. I have been struggling to find something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    GroupItemCount="5">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1">
      <tr runat="server" id="groupPlaceholder">
      </tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <GroupTemplate>
    <tr runat="server" id="tableRow">
      <td runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
    </tr>
  </GroupTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <td runat="server">
      <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
      <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
    </td>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```